# Same item SwiftUI List

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I have created a Core Data application which contains Order and CartProduct entities.
Order has one-to-many relationship with CartProduct and the inverse is to-one.

I add the products to the order, but there is a page where I want to display the products but looks like there is displayed only the last product.

```
@FetchRequest(
    entity: Order.entity(),
    sortDescriptors: [],
    predicate:NSPredicate(format: "status == %@", "ongoing")
) var orders: FetchedResults<Order>

func printProducts() {
    let array = orders[0].products!.array as! [CartProduct]
    for product in array {
        print("\(product.quantity) - \(product.name!)")
    }
}

var body: some View {
        if(!orders.isEmpty)
        {
            List(orders[0].products!.array as! [CartProduct]){product in
               Text("\(product.quantity) * \(product.name!)")
            }.onAppear(perform: printProducts) 
        }
}
```

In printProducts it prints the correct quantity of all the products, but in the list, only the quantity and name of the first product gets repeated (the number of products is correct).

Do you have any idea on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by adding `id` to the list.

```
@FetchRequest(
    entity: Order.entity(),
    sortDescriptors: [],
    predicate:NSPredicate(format: "status == %@", "ongoing")
) var orders: FetchedResults<Order>

func printProducts() {
    let array = orders[0].products!.array as! [CartProduct]
    for product in array {
        print("\(product.quantity) - \(product.name!)")
    }
}

var body: some View {
        if(!orders.isEmpty)
        {
            List(orders[0].products!.array as! [CartProduct], id: \.self){product in
               Text("\(product.quantity) * \(product.name!)")
            }.onAppear(perform: printProducts) 
        }
}
```